$n$ vertices and $n^2/4$ edges, have graph without triangles
i need to prove that for each even $n\ge2$ ,there is a simple undirected graph with $n$ vertices and $n^2/4$ edges, where there is not even $1$ triangle.
What I tried:
I tried to prove by induction on $n$.
Base case $n=2$, the only graph is without triangles.
Then I assume this is right for every $n$, and prove on $n+2$ ( the next even).
Given $n+2$ vertices and $(n+2)^2/4$ edges.
First I take random $n$ vertices and $n^2/4$ edges and using the induction assumstion to create a graph with no triangles in it.
Now, I'm left with $2$ vertices and $n+1$ edges to place.
First I connect the two vertices between them, now left with $n$ edges to place.
There I'm stuck. How do I place the left edges without creating a triangle?

By "verticals", do you mean "vertices"? $\quad$ My suggestion is for you to do this directly. There's an obvious candidate. As a further hint:  What class of graphs never has triangles?

yes i edited the post.
how can i do this directly ? you mean Bipartite Graphs?
the problem is that we didnt learnt it , and i just saw it on other question

Yes, I'm referring to Bipartite graphs. $\quad$ K, suppose you're not familiar with it, then look at small examples of $2, 4, 6, \ldots$ vertices and see if you can spot a pattern to extend them. $\quad$ As yet another hint, using your approach, show that there isn't a vertex from the original set of $n$ that is conncected to both of the new vertices. Then, what does this imply?

ok. following question :
i need to prove that for the same conditions , but number of edges > n^2/4 . that there is at elast 1 triangle in the graph .
i did induction , (base of n=0 , n=1, n=2).
then the the step of the induction is to prove for n+1 .
can i just say that if |E| > (n+1)^2/4 , it also greater then n^2/4 , and then because of the induction assumtion there is triangle?
i feel like im missing somthing

You don't need induction. Take the bipartite graph $K_{n/2,n/2}$. The graph has no triangles as it is bipartite. It has $n/2\times n/2=n^2/4$ edges.

What happens when $n$ is odd?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem

following question : i need to prove that for the same conditions , but number of edges > n^2/4 . that there is at elast 1 triangle in the graph . i did induction , (base of n=0 , n=1, n=2). then the the step of the induction is to prove for n+1 . can i just say that if |E| > (n+1)^2/4 , it also greater then n^2/4 , and then because of the induction assumtion there is triangle? i feel like im missing somthing
